# How do I use the results of a SQL query in a subsequent query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use the result set of a query in the `where` statement of a subsequent query.
Running into a problem because the first query returns multiple results and I don't know how to convert these to a comma-separated string for use in an `'IN' ()` statement.

```
$Result1 = mysql_query ("
select id from Table1
where
upper('$Input') = Employee_number   
")
or die(mysql_error());

$Result2 = mysql_query ("

Select * from table2 where ID in ($Result1)")
```

Comment: Beware that the `mysql` extension is deprecated and warnings will start appearing in PHP 5.5. You should move to `mysqli` (which has similar functions) or PDO. Such libraries also have prepared statements which will prevent SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query1 = mysql_query("
    select id from Table1 
    where upper('$Input') = Employee_number
") or die(mysql_error());

$ids = array();
while($Result1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
    $ids[] = $Result1['id'];
}

if(sizeof($ids))
{
    $n_ids = implode(',', $ids);

    $query2 = mysql_query("
        select * from Table2 
        where ID IN (" . $n_ids . ")
    ") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine this into a single MySQL statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM Table1 where upper('$Input') = Employee_number);
```

But if you really want to do it like in your question, you will probably have to lookup how to work with the results from `mysql_query`, just look that up in a function reference.